# How to match string that might be surrounded by additional characters, digits or special characters?

Tags: regex

I'm preparing labeled training data to train a spaCy model to detect certain named entities. For this purpose, I'm using a bunch of existing meeting notes and run my Regex extraction on it. It works quite well to extract the training data. When I'm training the model I have sometimes the issue (estimate is 10 - 15%) that the spaCy training function is complaining about:
Some entities could not be aligned in the text. When I look at the examples I see there sometimes issues that there are additional characters like "-" or digits or digits followed by "i" or if the notes are referring to multiple entities there is simply an "s" added at the end: Here are some examples:

- -test
- test123
- tests
- test2000i
- test 123
- test 2000i
- -tests test2000XPi

This is part of my regex to detect test.

```
|(test?(\s)?[0-9]{3,4}\w+)|(test?(\s)?\w+)|
```

*I think there is already a smarter way of doing this than doing it with ors |...*

How can I use regex to always match the whole string?

Comment: Like this? `^.*\btests?\s?(?:[0-9]{3,4})?[^\W\d]*$` https://regex101.com/r/gUxJB6/1

Comment: For each instance, please show us what the desired entity match is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the matches in the example data, you might use

```
-?\btests?\s?(?:[^\W\d]*\d{3,4})?[^\W\d]*
```

The pattern matches:

- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `\btests?` Match test or tests preceded by a word boundary
- `\s?` Match a whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\W\d]*` Match optional word chars except for digits
  - `\d{3,4}` Match 3 or 4 digits
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `[^\W\d]*` Match optional word chars except for digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wGQbKu/1)